# Application entry disappeared

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-gnome, .desktop, gnome-shell

I have a IntelliJ IDEA installed for some time already on my computer and today I have updated to a new version. After doing this I wanted to update my .desktop entry for this app in the `~/.local/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop`. The only thing I have changed is the number in the folder which defines the version. Once I have saved the file, the icon from the Launcher with favorites has disappeared. I can't find it anywhere, it's not listed in All applications neither. Where could be the problem? Copying the .desktop file to `/usr/share/applications/` didn't help, reseting Gnome conf to defaults didn't help. I don't know what else to try.

**jetbrains-idea.desktop**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Icon=/home/martin/Downloads/idea-IU-173.4301.25/bin/idea.png
Exec="/home/martin/Downloads/idea-IU-173.4301.25/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;GNOME;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

The only thing I have change before it disappeared are the lines 'Icon' and 'Exec' where I have changed the version number. And yes, I have checked it, it really exists. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, there was a problem with permissions of this file. Setting it to 644 solved the problem.